# How can I tell Python to append a string in a specific row in an array?

Tags: python, arrays

How can I append a new string into the third row? I tried `arrangement.append()` but I don't know how it would work.

Here is the list:

```
arrangement = [
["p1", "p2", "p3", "p4"],
["p5", "p6", "p7", "p8"],
["p9", "p10", "p11", "p12"],
["p13", "p14", "p15", "p16"]
]
```

I'm aware that there is something that I'm doing wrong or something that I just don't know yet.

Comment: Do you mean `arrangement[2].append(...)`?

Comment: Since the elements of ```arrangement``` are lists, you can simply do ```arrangement[2].append(..)``` where ```arrangement[2]``` is the 3rd list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each element `arrangement[i]` is a list (not array). You can index elements directly and call methods on them:

```
arrangement[2].append(some_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use:

```
arrangment[2].append("your string")
```

Python works in a way where the first item in a list is index 0, then the next is 1, and so on. You can get the value of an item in a list by its index by simply doing:

```
list_name[index] # index is what I explained above
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the elements of arrangement are lists, you can simply do `arrangement[2].append(..)` where `arrangement[2]` is the 3rd list:

```
arrangement = [
["p1", "p2", "p3", "p4"],
["p5", "p6", "p7", "p8"],
["p9", "p10", "p11", "p12"], #==== This list
["p13", "p14", "p15", "p16"]
]
```